# Non-bash questions posted under the bash tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, etiquette

Lately I am delving into advanced bash and I was a bit disappointed to see the number of posts under the 'bash' tag on SO that seem to have the tag due to some very minor association that has nothing to do with bash itself. For example, I just removed the tag from a post that was dominantly about PHP and contained a php function that took an argument with a stdout redirect in it.. i.e. func("foo.php > bar") somewhere in the 100 line PHP script was enough to convince the OP it was a bash question.

Of course, this is not an isolated incident. It seems epidemic that people apply the "bash" tag when the question really has very little or nothing to do with bash. I just removed the tag from 2 zsh questions for example, where the OP thought because he knew something in bash but not in zsh, and was asking how to do it in zsh, that it became a bash question.

That's like saying I don't know for loops in C, but look what I can do in assembly? Can you please teach me a for loop, then tagging the post with asm.

My thought is that I want to go on a personal crusade to remove bash tags from irrelevant posts, but I think I'll ask here before I step on too many toes. I already removed a couple

Thoughts?

Comment: My question is simple you'll bash your head on a wall.  *Tagged with:* [[tag:bash]]

Comment: If a tag holds no relevance to a question, edit it out. Simple as that really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Feel free, but just make sure to look at the post and fix *everything* about it, not just remove the tag:

- If it should be closed, then vote to close, and flag for moderator attention if it won't accumulate enough votes to close.
- If it shouldn't be closed, please fix formatting (code and otherwise), spelling, etc.
- Fix tags in other ways (don't just focus on removing the [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) tag, but add/remove more tags as necessary).

As long as you do that, you should be fine, but the first point is the most important; don't edit just to remove tags and leave bad questions out there, make sure something is done about them (hey, you'll get some badges along the way probably too!).

Comment: Agreed. If the questions are about *nix shells generally or shells other than bash there might be a better tag to replace the bash tag with.

Comment: Here's some of the other shell-ish tags that might work better than [tag:bash] for some questions: [tag:tcsh], [tag:csh], [tag:zsh], [tag:ksh], [tag:shell], [tag:sh], [tag:powershell]